# How to copy a column from a specific row all the way down to the last row with values?

Tags: excel, vba

I have two columns.. "AE" and "AG"

The headers are in row 4 of the worksheet and all the data starts from row 5 onwards.

I just want to copy the whole column of "AG" starting from "AG5" until the first blank row and paste it AS values into "AE" in the exact same range (starting from "AE5"). How can I go about doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Value transfer is faster than a copy and paste.

```
dim lr as long
with worksheets("sheet1")
    lr = .cells(.rows.count, "AG").end(xlup).row
    .range(.cells(5, "AE"), .cells(lr, "AE")) = .range(.cells(5, "AG"), .cells(lr, "AG")).value
end with
```

Comment: thanks but I did the suggested above..and it does not copy and paste as values..doesn't copy and paste at all..

Comment: Did you see the small edit I recently made? (change .Values to .Value) Did you change sheet1 to the correct name of your actual worksheet?

Comment: I'm sorry but I tested it and it works exactly as stated. Although difficult to read from a comment, your code looks sound. You should add it to your question through an edit where you can format it into a code block properly.

Comment: yes this is great..thanks!  it was a silly "." i was missing..sorry about that!

Answer (score 3):

Try below.

```
With ActiveSheet
    LR = .Range("AG1048576").End(xlUp).Row

    .Range("AG5:AG" & LR).Copy
    .Range("AE5").PasteSpecial xlValues
End With
```

You may need to change Activesheet to

```
sheets("NAME OF SHEET")
```

Comment: Code works fine here with a formula in AG and then values being pasted into AE. do you get an error or?